# Aggregate functions in a single query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering if any of you could help me out with this sql query below:MM

Table:
student_name, score, group, is_candidate

The relation b/w a student and a group is: a student can be in one group only and one group can have multiple students. A student can be a candidate or not a candidate.

I want to list all the groups in which its students may or may not be a candidate and also want to list the max(score) in each group while the max(score) should only be counted for the students who ARE candidates. Particularly, it's possible a group can have all students none of whom is a candidate, in that case max(Score) should just be a default value (say, 0).

Example:

```
student_A1, 90, group_A, true
student_A2, 92, group_A, true
student_A3, 95, group_A, false
student_B1, 85, group_B, false
student_B2, 65, group_B, false
student_B3, 75, group_B, false
student_C1, 91, group_C, true
```

The expected result is:

```
group_A, 92
group_B, 0
group_C, 91
```

My question is if it's possible to do this in one single query without having to join the table with itself to do a nested query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to only count the candidates;

```
SELECT "group", 
  MAX(CASE WHEN "is_candidate"='true' THEN "score" ELSE 0 END) max_score
FROM "mytable"
GROUP BY "group";
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f694d/1).